# Question from Gagilardo-Nirenberg Sobolev inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

[image]

Why the constant C in this inequality depends on $q$ but not depend on $u$.

In the proof $C= (\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u|^{(\gamma -1)\frac{p}{p-1}}dx )^\frac{p}{p-1}$.

Can anyone explain why it does not depend on $|u|$?

Comment: Can you point us to the proof in question? As stated, $C$ does seem to depend on $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what the proof tells you. It is derived
$$\left(\int |u|^{\frac{\gamma n}{n-1}}\right)^\frac{n-1}{n} \leq \gamma \left( 
 \int |u|^{(\gamma-1)\frac{p}{p-1}} \right)^\frac{p-1}{p} \|Du\|_{L^p}^p.$$
But the proof does not stop here. Now, $\gamma>1$ is chosen s.t. $\frac{\gamma n}{n-1}=(\gamma-1)\frac{p}{p-1}=p^*$, hence it implies
$$\left(\int |u|^{p^*}\right)^\frac{n-1}{n} \leq \gamma \left( 
 \int |u|^{p^*} \right)^\frac{p-1}{p} \|Du\|_{L^p}^p.$$
Hence
$$\left(\int |u|^{p^*}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}-\frac{p-1}{p}} \leq \gamma \|Du\|_{L^p}^p.$$
Notice $\frac{n-1}{n}-\frac{p-1}{p}=\frac{1}{p^*}$, i.e., $C=\gamma$.

Comment: Where is that proof? Neither the OP nor you are provided a reference for it... hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @ClementC.Ah sorry, the type setting told me that it's the book "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Fritz yes. Thanks I understand now. Can you help me to handle this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944360/how-do-i-prove-u-geq-beta-by-using-maximum-principle